# How to list Jenkins projects/jobs in system groovy only on master node?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

How do I list projects/job names in system Groovy only on master node?

To be more specific:

I need only list of jobs which runs on master. I don't want output any job which runs on slave nodes.

Comment: I don't get the question, you want to list jobs that will be run on master or what? Since all jobs will be on master, but you decide where they should be run with "Restrict where this project can be run".

Comment: Hi Matepe! Sorry to be not specific. As i said ... i need only list of jobs which runs on master! I don't want output any job which runs on slave nodes!

Comment: Perhaps your question is: "How do I list all builds that RAN" on the master? Or "How do I list all jobs that MAY RUN on the master?"  or "How do I list all builds that ARE RUNNING on the master.  Found your question because I'm looking for an answer to that last question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to list all jobs that has run on master, not that will be run on master... This script only checks the jobs that has actually run and isnt't removed/cleaned up.

http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractBuild.html#getBuiltOnStr()

```
import hudson.model.*

jenkins = Hudson.instance

items = jenkins.items

for (item in items){
  def job = item.getLastBuild()
  if(job != null){
        if(job.getBuiltOnStr() == null || job.getBuiltOnStr() == "")
          println "Built on master: " + job.toString()
  }
}
```

Comment: counter++ doesn't belong in the script :) or? :)

Comment: thanks! i have customized this to only display name of jobs that run on master by replacing **job.toString()** with **item.name**

Comment: Sorry no, will remove it, I use a counter to defined how many I want to edit/check before returning. Have had jobs that doesn't finish because they take too long time.

Comment: Hi there unfortunately this wont work if you have a pipeline job.

It fails with an error:

ERROR: Build step failed with exception groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.getBuiltOnStr() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)

If i delete pipeline job script runs successfully.

Any ideas?

Brgds, S.

Comment: Hmm, the methods getBuiltOnStr only exists for: http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractBuild.html
So in other cases your might have to assume that is run on master? Not really sure. I would check if job is AbstractBuild(if (obj instanceof C)), and if not, then skip and assume it runs on master.

Comment: Worflow (pipeline) jobs can run wherever specified by the "node" pipeline syntax though by default they all initially run on the master. The only way to really know where a job MIGHT RUN is to inspect the pipeline file. However you can enumerate all builds that ARE RUNNING on the master - but the only way I have found to do this is costly.

Comment: Script also fails for me: `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.getBuiltOnStr() is applicable for argument types: () values: []` is there any other script we can use?